# How to change end_of_week with cweek

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use `.cweek`, it returns the weeks by commercial weeks. So, for my weekly charts, if I choose a `start_date` which starts a Thursday for example, the data is not grouped by week from Thursday to Wednesday, but from Thursday to Sunday.

Do you know a way to tell to cweek that the end day of a week is equal to the selected date and not to Sunday?

I would like something like when you have a date object and you set `date.beginning_of_week(start_day = :thursday)`?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
customer_signup_chart = {
        type: 'line',
        data: [],
        label: 'blabla'
}

users = User
        .where('created_at > :start_date AND created_at < :end_date',
          start_date: start_date.beginning_of_day,
          end_date: end_date.end_of_day)
        .select(:created_at, :typology)

start_day = start_date.strftime('%A').downcase.to_sym
datasets = { labels: (start_date.to_datetime..end_date.to_datetime).map {|date| date.beginning_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime("From %d/%m to #{date.end_of_week(start_day = start_day).strftime('%d/%m')}")}.uniq}

users = users.group_by {|u| u.created_at.to_date.cweek}

loop do
   customer_signup_chart[:data] << (users[start_date.to_date.cweek] ? users[start_date.to_date.cweek].count {|u| u.typology == 'client'} : 0)
   start_date += 1.week
   break if start_date > end_date
end
```

This returns `users group_by created_at` in the same week, but for Ruby, the same week is from Monday to Sunday and not from `start_date` to `start_date - 1.day`.

I don't know if it's more understandable now..

**EDIT 2:**

Well, it makes me add a gem only for four charts but I'm going to use groupdate, it's probably the simplest way to do this..

Comment: Could you add a small reproducible example. It's not clear from the question how you call `cweek`, on what you call it, what the result is and what you want. `cweek` returns the week number. Where did week days come from?

Comment: Hi @ndn, I edited my post

Comment: I see. So basically, if we take the current date (11.10.2018) it during the second week of this October if we count weeks as starting Monday and ending Sunday. But it's the third week if we count weeks as ending Tuesday (for example). If that was it - then no, `cweek` implements the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard so weeks start from Monday.

Comment: You're right, but in my case it's a problem, let me show you a small video example: https://i.gyazo.com/e8815e9f112aac2c70a3bcef4c42bfeb.mp4 As you can see, if the start_date is a Monday everything is OK, I have my users week by week, but if the start_date is Wednesday, the data of weeks other than the first doesn't change because the data still from Monday to Sunday..

Comment: You have to add a +-1 offset that you calculate yourself. There is no option available to `cweek` for this.